# ruby pry whereami command not working

Tags: ruby, rspec, pry

I'm working with pry 0.10.1 java and pry-nav 0.2.4 on jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392). In the middle of an rspec step after invoking binding.pry, I type the pry command:

```
whereami
```

All I get is

```
ArgumentError: Symbol or String expected, but NilClass given.
from /Users/yc98js1/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/helpers/plugin.rb:215:in `validate_id'
```

whereamI going wrong? [pun intended]

Comment: Does `@` work? (alias of whereami)

Comment: Always found that JRuby and pry don't play nice together. Worth debugging in MRI and running your specs with JRuby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the error was thrown by the coderay gem. Could be a collision of this gem with another.
It might be unrelated but its hiding the error. try uninstalling coderay first and running the code again.